# How to build an online quiz that allows for partial scores and shows a running total of points?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, forms, survey

I'm trying to build a simple website that will help people determine if they are eligible for a particular government program. Eligibility is determined by points in various categories (age, occupation, education, language skills, etc.).

For example:
Education
PhD - 5 points
Masters - 3 points
Bachelors - 1 point
None of the above - 0 points

The website would just be a form with a list of questions. Each question in the form would represent one of the categories mentioned above, and a user would select the answer that applies to them. The form would show the user how many points their answer is worth, and keep a running tally.

I can almost build the site using the 'quiz' function in Google Forms and then embedding that form on a Google Sites page. The problem that I'm finding is that with Google Forms and many other various online form building tools is that they don't allow for partial scores. There's simply right answers worth full points and wrong answers worth no points.

I tried out a LOT of online form builder tools from this list, all with the problem I just described: https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/quiz-maker

Ideally, the running tally would be visible the whole time, not just at the end.

Another wish: For each answer I'd be able to provide feedback that appears live based on the choices the users pick.

Does anyone know of an online tool that will let me build a form such as this?

(In case people are wondering: I don't work for said government, and I don't need to save user data, handle logins, collection information from users, etc. The website would just be a form that gives an estimated score.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself!

I had been searching through results for "form builder", but it turns out I should have been searching for "calculator builder". Once I did that I found a number of free and freemium online tools that do what I was looking for. What I was able to build looks *much* nicer than what I would have gotten from a form or coding something myself.

Here's a list of calculator builder products: https://alternativeto.net/software/ucalc/. I personally went with Calconic_ for my site since it was the only one with a free option (not just a free trial) that I was able to successfully embed into the website I built.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this with Microsoft Forms and then send them a mail with Microsoft Flow.

Comment: Microsoft Forms, similar to Google Forms, doesn't allow for partial points.